# Convert MySQL ERD Design View to PDF or Image Form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **Large ERD** in **MySQL** which is showing the **relationships** between all **entities**.

Now i want to **Convert** that **(Sorted Diagram)** into a **PDF** or **Image** Form,

So that it become **easy** to **View** and **Analyze**.

Comment: What is your question? And what software do you use?

Comment: @davey I user PhpMyAmdin. I want my ERD Design on PDF or Image

Comment: Take a look at Mysql Workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), you can import (Reverse engineer) your database and export an ERD.